# How can I show that $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{\lambda\cos(t)}}{e^{itn}}dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\lambda\cos(t)}e^{itn}dt$?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

In a solution of an excersise I have found $$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{\lambda\cos(t)}}{e^{itn}}dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\lambda\cos(t)}e^{itn}dt$$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$. Why is that right? I have tried to use substitution.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using substitution again. What is $\cos(2\pi-t)$? What is $e^{1(2\pi-t)n}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following David's hint, try to calculate
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\exp(\lambda\cos(2\pi-t))}{\exp(-i(2\pi-t)n)}\ dt\tag{*}
$$
with $u=2\pi-t$ and relate $(*)$ to the LHS of your identity.

Comment: I got it :) Thanks.